# C++ - create a bucket of instantiations for any lambda

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, instantiation, static-polymorphism

I want to create several instantiations of templated-lambda in one place. The number of instantiations and parameters of each are known at compilation time so I assume that this could be possible. This is generic illustration of what I want to do:

```
enum class Format
{
    FORMAT_1,
    FORMAT_2
    //, ...
};

template<Format F>
struct SomeData
{
    //...
};

template < template<Format> typename Processing >
struct ProcessingForAllFormats
{
    Processing<Format::FORMAT_1> processingObject1;
    Processing<Format::FORMAT_2> processingObject2;
    //...
};

template < template<Format> typename Processing >
decltype(auto) makeProcessingForAllFormats(Processing lambda)
{
    //I know this function is completely wrong as
    //concrete instantation needs concrete type as an argument
    //instead of a template
    return ProcessingForAllFormats<Processing>();
}

int main() {
    auto processing = makeProcessingForAllFormats(
        [](SomeData<auto> data) {/*...*/}
        );
    return 0;
}
```

This is simplified image of my problem. In one word - I want to store instantiations of processings for any SomeData objects for future use. I don't know if it is possible in C++14 or even C++17. And I know this would be easy if I use dynamic polymorphism instead of static one but performance means a lot for me in this case.

**EDIT:**

As TartanLlama noticed - using functors is indeed simpler to implement but much harder to use. I treat `Format`, `SomeData` and `ProcessingForAllFormats` like if it was a part of library/API and I want give user of that "liblary" as much ease-of-use as I can. Lambdas are intended to provide that. @AndyG's sugestion is useful - for lambdas ProcessingForAllFormats implementation must be diferent. But I don't have idea if lambda-templates in C++14/17 are powerful enough to build such API.

Comment: side note: you should switch from template<Format> typename to template<Format> class, otherwise you'll trigger pedantic warnings in certain compilers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about wrapping generic lambda with interface restricted to your desired types:

```
enum class Format
{
    FORMAT_1,
    FORMAT_2
    //, ...
};

template<Format F>
struct SomeData
{
    //...
};

template <typename GenericProcessing, Format format>
struct Restrictor
{
    Restrictor(GenericProcessing genericProcessingObject)
        : genericProcessingObject(genericProcessingObject)
    {}

    decltype(auto) operator()(SomeData<format> data)
    {
        return genericProcessingObject(data);
    }

private:
    GenericProcessing genericProcessingObject;    
};

template <typename GenericProcessing>
struct ProcessingForAllFormats
{
    Restrictor<GenericProcessing, Format::FORMAT_1> processingObject1;
    Restrictor<GenericProcessing, Format::FORMAT_2> processingObject2;
    //...

    ProcessingForAllFormats(GenericProcessing genericProcessingObject)
        : processingObject1(genericProcessingObject)
        , processingObject2(genericProcessingObject)
        //...
    {}
};

template <typename GenericProcessing>
decltype(auto) makeProcessingForAllFormats(GenericProcessing genericProcessingObject)
{
    return ProcessingForAllFormats<GenericProcessing>(genericProcessingObject);
}

int main() {
    auto processing = makeProcessingForAllFormats(
        [](auto data) {/*...*/});
    processing.processingObject1(SomeData<Format::FORMAT_1>{}); // ok
    //processing.processingObject1(SomeData<Format::FORMAT_2>{}); // fail by design, expects SomeData<Format::FORMAT_1>
    //processing.processingObject2(SomeData<Format::FORMAT_1>{}); // fail by design, expects SomeData<Format::FORMAT_2>
    processing.processingObject2(SomeData<Format::FORMAT_2>{}); // ok
}
```

Comment: This answer is interesting. I should find the way to change `auto data` to `SomeData<auto> data` in my free time.

Comment: @jaskmar that's not possible though.

Comment: Unfortunately it only works with `concepts lite` enabled which is not part of standard. That's make me sad.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this with a lambda sounds like a big pain, as it's not the closure which is generated from a template, it's the `operator()`. This is much easier with a functor template:

```
enum class Format
{
    FORMAT_1,
    FORMAT_2
    //, ...
};

template<Format F>
struct SomeData
{
    //...
};

template < template<Format> typename Processing >
struct ProcessingForAllFormats
{
    Processing<Format::FORMAT_1> processingObject1;
    Processing<Format::FORMAT_2> processingObject2;
    //...
};

template <Format F>
struct Processor {
    void operator() (SomeData<F> data) { /*...*/ } 
};

int main() {
    auto processing = ProcessingForAllFormats<Processor>{};
}
```

Comment: I agree with this answer. One doesn't really create "instances" of a lambda. They don't have default constructors.

Comment: I agree with you dudes. But please take a look at the EDIT